# Choosing which system to run

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have two HDDs in raid-0, and one ssd. I installed windows on ssd partition (NTFS) first, and then I installed linux on the second ssd partition (ext4). Both through booting and with formatting everything.

The problem now is that windows opens by default, without giving me any choice to choose linux. I have `windows boot manager` as first priority in boot settings, other priories are just discs.

Also, on windows I see only windows partition, I don't see the linux one. It's just like it doesn't exist.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try installing GRUB or GRUB2 and using it as the primary bootloader.

Comment: I dont see linux there. The thing is that after restarting system after choosing installation partition during linux installation, windows boots up.

Comment: What if you manually chose to boot from the Linux partition in the BIOS?